# Need help to create (or convert) a service for Slackware

Tags: systemd, sysvinit, slackware

I recently switched to Slackware. I want to use NordVPN. The problem is, they only provide .rpm and .deb packages.
But that's not really important. I just extracted .rpm contents and the program is working just fine now.
The only thing that bothers me is that I have to run its daemon manually. I know that Slackware does not use systemd, so tried to create a service for it, or convert its own systemd service, but I failed.
I would appreciate if anyone can help me.
Here's the systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=NordVPN Daemon
Requires=nordvpnd.socket
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nordvpnd
NonBlocking=true
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

and here's the socket:

```
[Unit]
Description=NordVPN Daemon Socket
PartOf=nordvpnd.service

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/nordvpnd.sock
NoDelay=true

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Comment: *tried to create a service (...) but I failed* - what did you try exactly? what was not working? did you look at other scripts in `/etc/rc.d/` directory? btw. there are tools for installing `rpm` packages on Slackware.

Comment: @rsm the question is not about installing, the OP is asking people to write him a script. Some packages nowadays only come with systemd files.

Comment: Actually, i could finally write a very simple script with 3 functions of start, restart and stop, and it works perfectly now. Anyway Thanks you guys

Comment: Why did you switch to Slackware, if you need to run software that doesn't support it directly?

Answer (score 1):

That would probably something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
NordVPN_start(){
    if [ -x /usr/sbin/nordvpnd ] ; then
        /usr/sbin/nordvpnd
    fi
}

NordVPN_stop(){
    /bin/killall NordVPN 2>/dev/null
}

case "$1" in
'start')
  NordVPN_start
  ;;
'stop')
  NordVPN_stop
  ;;
'reload')
  NordVPN_stop
  NordVPN_start
  ;;
'restart')
  NordVPN_stop
  NordVPN_start
  ;;

*) 
  echo "usage $0 start|stop|reload|restart"
esac
```